# Server session management in GWTP

Tags: session, gwt, rest

I have few basic questions on session management in GWTP.

1. Now, we create a new session when the user logs in to application. Now, I can open a browser and type in the app url with a token directly without logging in. It will render the UI page to user without any checks. Now, we have session checks in server side. So if the UI page make s a server call on rendering then only, I will get to know session is not valid and i can redirect him to login page. But, how do we handle the cases where UI page does not have any server side logic and user directly paste the URL with that token.

Do I have to make a server call on every page request from GWTP presenter just to check session is valid? or do we have any other approaches to it?

1. I am not passing any explicit session id param from GWT Client to server. Its only the JSessionId getting passed automatically from browser to server. We just do request.getSession() in server and see if it is null or not(Not logged in if null). So I hope we dont have any security issues with this. Please confirm.
2. With GWT client running on android and server side logic exposed as Restful Web services using Jersey, how do we maintain session because Restful WS are stateless. Now how do we achieve user session in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. you don't required to make server call every time. when u logged then set current user only once in logged keeper class. @UseGatekeeper annotation check current user instance only not make any server call. if current user is exist then It will return true from canReveal method. 
And It will allow to access that presenter name token in url.

Suppose you don't required any session access it then use @NoGatekeeper instead of it.

```
>> let me know if the understanding is fine with your solution. Also, what about point 2 and 3 questions?
```

A.1  U can use jsession there is no any security issue.
A.2  By using JSESSION id, u can pass jsession id to do server call because server do work if it will get same session.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable inputs. I will implement the same logic. I am waiting for the third question inputs from anybody and will close the topic later.

Comment: I have one more very basic question. Sorry if it is too silly...I will get the User object once i am done with a server call. But GIN would have already created all objects in the beginning and LoggedInGateKeeper would have created with null user. How do I inject CurrentUser member with my server returned value?

Comment: You just set @NoGatekeeper annotation for home presenter.set logged user(Current user bean object) on login. I think u get idea for other presenter it will provide u current user. And assign current user is null After logout.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally i got it worked. Am just hoping somebody would comment on my last point (Session in restful WS)

Answer (score 0):

Although security should always be enforced server-side, you probably don't want regular users to take a peek at your administration pages. In GWTP, you can prevent some presenters from revealing themselves by creating your custom Gatekeeper classes.

```
@Singleton
public class LoggedInGatekeeper implements Gatekeeper {  

  private final CurrentUser currentUser;

  @Inject
  public LoggedInGatekeeper (
      final CurrentUser currentUser ) {
    this.currentUser = currentUser;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean canReveal() {
    return currentUser.isLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

Then you simply need to add the `@UseGatekeeper` annotation to the proxy of each presenter you want to protect:

```
  @ProxyCodeSplit
  @NameToken("userSettings")
  @UseGatekeeper( LoggedInGatekeeper.class )
  public interface MyProxy extends ProxyPlace<MainPagePresenter> {}
```

You must make sure that your custom ginjector has a `getLoggedInGatekeeper()` method. In your ginjector you can also use the `@DefaultGatekeeper` method to annotate the get method returning the Gatekeeper class you want to use for any proxy that is not annotated with `@UseGatekeeper`. If you use a `@DefaultGatekeeper` and would like to specify that a proxy shouldn't use any gatekeeper, then use the `@NoGatekeeper` annotation on that proxy.

You must make sure that the presenter handling errors is not using a Gatekeeper otherwise you risk running in an error. For this reason, it's good practice to annotate this presenter's proxy with `@NoGatekeeper`. The presenter handling errors is the one revealed by your custom PlaceManager's `revealErrorPlace` method. If you do not override that method, then it's the one revealed by your `revealDefaultPlace` method.

Refer to the [GWTP docs](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted) for more info

Comment: What i understand from above is that, you have to make a server call to finally know whether user is logged in or not and if I want to have a check on all presenters in my application, then on every page request we do a server call using GateKeeper approach whether user is logged in or not. let me know if the understanding is fine with your solution.  Also, what about point 2 and 3 questions?